# How to serve a PNG with flask so it can be used as an attachment in Slack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send a PNG as an attachment, but it doesn't show up in Slack. I am setting the right parameters in the POST-method, but Slack refuses to use the image I am providing.

I am using flask to serve the static files:

```
@app.route('/data/<path:path>')
def send_png(path):
    response = make_response(send_file("data/" + path))
    return response
```

When I call the URL in my browser, the files gets displayed without any issues. When I pass the URL to slack as an attachment, the file doesn't show up.

When I pass the URL of an imgur-image, the attachment **does** get displayed.

For that reason, I assume the issue lies somewhere in the content-type/file-headers of the files flask serves.

My file headers are:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 391777
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Mar 2018 22:46:41 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Expires: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 12:48:53 GMT
ETag: "1520030801.2465587-391777-4064615867"
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.11 Python/3.5.2
Date: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 00:48:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I can also verify, that Slack does request my attachment (just doesn't display it, as said before):

```
[('User-Agent', 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)'), ('X-Forwarded-For', '54.89.92.4'), ('Content-Type', ''), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate'), ('Accept', '*/*'), ('Host', 'XXXXXXXXXX'), ('Referer', 'https://slack.com'), ('Content-Length', ''), ('X-Forwarded-Proto', 'https')]
```

Comment: As I understand, the image is stored in your file system, and you want to send it to Slack. You are attempting to use a flask server to host images at given urls?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Opening those images in the browser does work, I can see Slack requesting them, they just never show up as an attachment in Slack.

Comment: When you enter the url on another device (ie phone), do you see the same pictures?

Comment: Yes, I do see the same pictures on other devices.

Comment: imgur uses http2.0, don't know if that matters. I don't think I am able to help further, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:, the image should go in `files=` if you want as an attachment

```
import io
import requests
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('picture.png')
im = io.BytesIO(img.file.read())
r = requests.post("127.0.0.1", data=im, timeout=5, files=im)
```